# Using download manager in andorid 11 and the impact of scoped storage

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-11

**What I am doing**

- I am trying to use the Download Manager to download a file to the device
  internal storage
- Internal storage referring to the location `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.code/files/Download/Devrath/test.db`
- Now I am using an emulator below is the code which is working and successfully able to download the file

**Questions**

1. Will the scoped storage affect this in the future?
2. Or Since Download manager is a system service, will it continue to
   work

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.code">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Code">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivityTwo">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.code"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

**MainActivityTwo**

```
public class MainActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    //public static final String imageURL = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_tutorial.pdf";
    public static final String imageURL = "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test10Mb.db";
    // String imageName = "java_tutorial.pdf";

    String filePath = "";
    String imageName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        filePath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString()
                .concat(File.separator)
                .concat("Devrath").concat(File.separator);

        imageName = "test.db";

        // storage runtime permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

        Button btnDownloadImage = findViewById(R.id.initiateDownloadId);
        Button chkIfFileExistsId = findViewById(R.id.chkIfFileExistsId);
        btnDownloadImage.setOnClickListener(v -> downloadImage(imageURL, imageName));
        chkIfFileExistsId.setOnClickListener(v -> checkIfFileExists());

    }

    public void downloadImage(String url, String outputFileName) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setTitle(imageName);
        request.setDescription("Downloading " + imageName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, outputFileName); // ---> Working
        //request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator, outputFileName);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,filePath, outputFileName);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    }

    private void checkIfFileExists() {

        //-> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.code/files/Download/Devrath/test.db
        File mFile = new File(filePath.concat(imageName));
        if(mFile.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"File exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"File does not exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to use DownloaderManager you need to give standard directory only like Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES. Also if your sdk is 30 then you must store as scope storage. You need to save files as per its type like if you are downloading images you need to download it in "Pictures" folder, if it audio then need to download in "Music".

If your sdk is not 30 and using DownloadManager than also need to use standard directory. Or you can use AsyncTask to download anywhere.

Comment: @pratikvekariya .... If I am using a Download manager and storing to `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` and downloading a text file .... Then still I need to use scope storage?

Comment: If your sdk is 30 or later then you must need to use scope storage whether you are using DownloadManager or AsyncTask. I think you can download txt file in "Download" otherwise use "Documents" directory.

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,filePath, outputFileName);` Did you test that code? As it cannot work. filePath should be no full path but only a folder. You are supplying a full path.

Comment: `Then still I need to use scope storage? – ` Bad question. Or you use setDestinationInExternalFilesDir or setDestinationInExternalStorageDirectory or use an uri. Under Android 11 you can use all. Some simple tests will show you.

Comment: @blackapps .... I have tested the above code and the file is successfully getting downloaded ... It's a working code!

Comment: @Devrath I have downloaded your code and working on same problem like you had.
And your code which you posted in question isn't working. Do you remeber what to change? I was trying with different methods with setDestination~

Comment: @WiktorKalinowski .... I have posted a solution that I made for my use case. hope it helps you. Please check the Github link in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I ended up using the app's internal storage...  I have created a GitHub project.
- Posting here so it will help someone.
- There is a Complete working solution I made

[GIT-HUB - Link](https://github.com/devrath/ubiquitous-downloadmanager)

Comment: Just a few thoughts about your Repo: Exclude those useless `.DS_Store` files and use meaningful commit messages: "v" and "x" are not really helpful and don't look very professional which does not match your github profile ;-) I would suggest if you don't own a custom domain that you use the namespace `com.github.devrath` that identifies your code nicely

Comment: can you provide java code :)